# Extrair elementos de uma List

Tags: r

Tenhos essa list:

```
a <- list()
  a[[1]] <- matrix(c(1,2),nrow = 2)
```

Como faço para selecionar o elemento 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para acessar o elemento 2 da matriz na lista primeiramente você tem que acessar a matriz  -- `a[[1]]` pois é o primeiro elemento da lista -- e depois acessar o segundo elemento da matriz -- `a[[1]]][[2]]` ou `a[[1]][2]`.

```
a[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2
```